# Theorem 5-2 Spivak's Calulus on Manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds

[image]

[image]

My question is :

1) How to show  $H(f(y)=y$?$H(f(y))=(h^1(f(y)),\dots,h^k(f(y)))=?$

2)How we get $det g'(a,b)=det(D_jf^i(a))$

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
H(f(y)) &= H(h^{-1}(\underbrace{y}_{\in \Bbb{R}^k},\underbrace{0}_{\in \Bbb{R}^{n-k}}))  \\
    &= (h^1(h^{-1}(y,0)), \dots, h^k(h^{-1}(y,0)))  \\
    &= (y^1, \dots, y^k)  \\
    &= y  \text{.}
\end{align*}

For the other, note that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial a} = \begin{pmatrix} (D_j f^i(y) ) \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial b} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \Bbb{I}_{n-k} \end{pmatrix}$, so $g' = \begin{pmatrix} (D_j f^i(y) )_{i=1}^k & (D_j f^i(y) )_{i=k+1}^n \\ 0 & \Bbb{I}_{n-k} \end{pmatrix}$
\begin{align*}
\det g' &= \det (D_j f^i(y) )_{i=1}^k \det \Bbb{I}_{n-k} - \det (D_j f^i(y) )_{i=k+1}^n \cdot 0  \\
    &= \det (D_j f^i(y) )_{i=1}^k  \\
    &= \det (D_j f^i(y) )  \text{,}  
\end{align*}

where the last equality is perhaps most easily seen by the evaluation of the determinant by recursive minors starting with all the $1$s in the $\Bbb{I}_{n-k}$.

It might be helpful to mentally tag the various objects as they are made:

- $U$ is an open neighborhood in $\Bbb{R}^n$ of $x \in M$,
- $V$ is an open neighborhood in $\Bbb{R}^n$, with the convenient property that
- $h$ maps $U$ to $V$, flattening $M$ out so that the image of $M$ lies on the subspace with last $n-k$ coordinates equal to zero, and maps points of $U \smallsetminus M$ "above" and "below" that subspace,
- $W$ is that image of $U \cap M$ in $\Bbb{R}^k$ where we drop the $n-k$ superfluous zero coordinates,
- $f$ maps the $W$ patch of $\Bbb{R}^k$ to $M$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$,
- $H$ is the canonical projection of $h$ onto its first $k$ coordinates; this is another way to get from $U$ to $\Bbb{R}^k$, but it is far from invertible (it is not injective) and is not required to land exactly on $W$.  However, $W$ is mapped to itself pointwise by this projection, so $H$ must have $\mathrm{rank}\, H \geq \dim W = k$ on points of $U \cap M$ (and it can't be greater because $H$ maps to $\Bbb{R}^k$),
- $g$ maps the (filled) cylinder over $W$ by taking the $W$-part to its point of $U \cap M$ and just adding the last $n-k$ coordinates of its input to the last $n-k$ coordinates of that point of $U \cap M$.  This makes $g'$ a block matrix with $f'$ as the upper-left block, the identity matrix in the lower right, and zeroes in the other two blocks,
- ...

Comment: What i understood from your matrix $g'$,matrix $(D_jf^i(a))=0$,$1 \leq j \leq k$ and $ k+1 \leq i \leq n$.My question is why this is zero?

Comment: @mathstudent : Oops!  Those are cut-and-paste errors.  Fixed (and expanded a little).

Comment: How $ f^\prime (y) $ will have $rank$ $ k$ can you explain please ?

Comment: @mathstudent : "$H'(f(y)) \cdot f'(y) = I$" forces both $H'(f(y))$ and $f'(y)$ to be invertible, hence both have maximal rank, $k$ here.  This follows from $H(f(y)) = y$ and the chain rule.

Comment: from theorem 2-11,we have there  is a open set $V_1^\prime $ containing $(y,0)$ and an open set $V_2^\prime $ containing $g(y,0)=x$ such that $g:V_1^\prime \to V_2^\prime $ has a differentiable inverse $h:V_2^\prime \to V_1^\prime $.My question is why $h$ is used as the differentiable inverse of $g$?

Comment: @mathstudent : Strictly, after "Suppose, conversely, ..." the use of $h$ need have no relation with the prior use of $h$.  We are starting the proof in the opposite direction, so our variables are unbound (unless we say otherwise).  However, this $h$ is the same as the above $h$.  "$g(a,b) = f(a) + (0,b)$" (following the "Suppose, conversely, ...") and "$f(a) = h^{-1}(a,0)$" (from the previous half-proof).  Furthre, the $f$ in the second half is the same as the $f$ in the first half.  This re-use of notation is "suggestive".  Have you drawn a picture to help you follow these maps?

Comment: If i take $f$ in converse case as $f_1$,so i will have $f_1(a)=g(a,0)$.And we have $f(a)=h^{-1}(a,0)$ from first half.And you said ,the $f$ in the second half is same as the $f$ in the first half .So,how can i prove $f=f_1$?Or if i can say $f_1(a)=(g^{-1})^{-1}(a,0)$,how can i show that $g^{-1}=h$?

Comment: I quoted the two facts needed for this argument.  Put them together.  It might help you to notice that the argument in the proof only makes this claim, $g^{-1} = h$, on the $(a,0)$ slice of $V_1$.

Comment: how we get $f(W) \cap U=${$f(a):(a,0) \in V_1^\prime$}? and how continuity of $f^{-1}$ used here?,I am not getting! I know $f(W)=${$f(a):a \in W$}={$f(a):(a,0) \in h(M)$}I know, i am asking too much questions,I am doing this all self study.

Comment: @mathstudent : You have been given two strategies for organizing the many sets and maps in this proof:  from the Answer, carefully describe each symbol as it appears and *write that down* so you can refer to it, and from the comments, draw a (large) carefully labelled picture showing the pieces of the objects that are called out and the maps among the various pieces.  Your many questions are strong evidence that you are not producing these aides to understanding.

Comment: can u suggest me some good reference book for the topic?

Comment: @mathstudent : The problem in this Question is introductory manifold material.  Almost any "intro. to manifolds" will have a result similar to this almost immediately after defining "manifold".  You might also benefit from Google searching on [coordinate charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold#Coordinate_charts) and [Atlas (of charts)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology)).

Comment: Why are we to understand that $W$ as initially defined is open in $R^k$?

Comment: @Drooga : Either "... an open set $W \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ ..." or condition (2) wants $f'(y)$ to be defined at every $y \in W$ which requires an open neighborhood of $y$ in $W$ (the union of all of which is open, so $W$ is open).  (If this last is not clear, try taking the derivative of a function whose domain is a (closed) single point.)